# Вывести только определенные регионы страны

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно вывести яндекс карту, на которой будут отмечены только определенные области или регионы страны. Возможно с какой-то своей заливкой..

Answer (score 1):

на JavaScript можно вот так:

```
ymaps.geoQuery(ymaps.regions.load("RU", {
    lang: "ru",
    quality: sQualityMain
})).search('properties.hintContent = "Костромская область"').setOptions({   strokeColor: sColorMain,    strokeWidth: sWidthMain,fillColor: 'rgba(0,10,205, 0.1)'}).addToMap(map);
```